# Incorporating GAE backend instance to a task that is run for 3 seconds every minute

Tags: google-app-engine

I notice there are 9 hours per day of free backend quota. Will my "every 1 minute" cron job, that runs for 3 seconds, be able to run within the 9 hour quota? i.e. will it properly auto shutdown after a few seconds?

i.e if the three second job finishes and the backend is shutdown within 20 seconds of it starting, that should fit within the 9 hours? or do backends stay up for longer than this?

Comment: Do I get your question correctly, the process takes 3 seconds to run and 20 seconds to shut down, which makes (59*23*24)/(60*60) ~ 9.05 hours per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a billing/pricing question than a programming question, but [the FAQ about pricing granularity in App Engine states](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#time_granularity_instance_pricing):

> Instances are charged for their uptime in addition to a 15-minute startup fee. If you have a dynamic instance only serving traffic for 5 minutes, you will pay for 5+15 minutes. Additionally, if the instance stops and then starts again within a 15 minute window, the startup fee will only be charged once and the instance will be considered "up" for the time that passed.

So based on the scenario that you described above, the backend instance will still be billed as running continuously without interruption.